# Block not showing after layout update

Tags: magento-1.9, module, layout, blocks, magento-community

Considering this layout update XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.0.1">
    <checkout_cart_index>
        <reference name="methods">
            <block type="mhquote/request_link" name="mhquote.request.link" as="mhquoteRequestLink" before="-" template="mhquote/request/link.phtml" />
            <remove name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage" />
            <remove name="checkout.cart.methods.multishipping" />
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
</layout>
```

When the update is applied the cart page goes from this:

[image: Before]

To this:

[image: After]

I can't understand why the new block is not shown, given that:

- a module exists which has `mhquote` as a unique handler
- the module is correctly set as for controllers in it work fine
- `methods` block is a `core/text_list` block, so it should automatically render all child blocks
- the template exists at `app/design/frontend/<current_theme>/default/template/mhquote/request/link.phtml`
- the `Disc_Quote_Block_Request_Link` block class exists and extends from `Mage_Core_Block_Template`, `Disc_Quote` being the class group handled by `mhquote`
- the layout update file is loaded correctly as it successfully removes the two checkout links

The block template is really simple, just a `<div>` with a string I'd like to show:

```
<div class="hellotest">
     <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

I can't see where I'm wrong. I keep checking and rewriting it from scratch paying more attention to the namings but I can't seem to show that block.

Any idea why? Thanks in advance for your help.

**=== EDIT 1 ===**

This is the `config.xml` for the module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Disc_Quote>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Disc_Quote>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <mhquote>
                <class>Disc_Quote_Block</class>
            </mhquote>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <mhquote>
                <class>Disc_Quote_Helper</class>
            </mhquote>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <mhquote>
                <class>Disc_Quote_Model</class>
            </mhquote>
        </models>
    </global>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <mhquote>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>    
                    <module>Disc_Quote</module>
                    <frontName>mhquote</frontName>
                </args>
            </mhquote>
        </routers>

        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mhquote>
                    <file>mhquote.xml</file>
                </mhquote>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>

</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign block permission from system > Permission > Block > Add New Block

[image]

click on Save Block.
Once clear the cache and refresh the page
Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, after applying your solution, the block still does not show.

Comment: My pleasure, Make sure about correct block type and phtml path  and Make sure that block name doesn't conflict with another.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, I posted the module's config.xml for reference.